# Blocking https url's in a embedded gecko browser

Tags: ssl, https, embedding, gecko, nss

I have an application in which a gecko browser is embedded. The application is crashing when I try to access any https url's because nss is not properly initialised at this point. The crash is in PK11_TokenExists(). I want to block my browser from rendering https sites. If a user clicks on a https link I can block that load in OnStartURI() of nsIURIContentListener.But if the user types in say orkut.com I wont know in OnStartURI() whether its a http url or a https one(i.e. whether it will use SSL or not). I wanted to know how I can block https url's in such cases?

Thanks
jbsp72

Answer (score 2):

I would first try to figure out why your application is crashing on HTTPS/SSL connections.  I think it would be better to fix the crash than trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this the following way:

Implement the `OnStateChange` method of the `nsIWebProgressListener` interface.

Check the parameter `aStateFlags`: If this parameter contains the flags `STATE_IS_DOCUMENT` and `STATE_START`, then a new location is being navigated to.

To find out the URL, use the parameter `aRequest`. It has type `nsIRequest`, but cast it to type `nsIChannel`. Then read the `URI` property. This contains the URL being navigated to.

In case the URI starts with "https", abort the navigation by calling the `cancel` method of the parameter `aRequest`, passing `NS_BINDING_ABORTED` as a parameter.